# Rails_apps_composer. Generate an application from defaults. error :undefined method `add_builtin_type' for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: build-automation, railsapps, rails-composer

I'm trying use Rails_app_composer “automatically”, from a defaults file that specifies parameters.

I use to generate an application from defaults:

```
$ rails_apps_composer new lamevapp --defaults=my_defaults.yaml
```

my_defaults.yaml is

```
recipes:
- setup
- readme
- gems
- testing
- email
- models
- controllers
- views
- routes
- frontend
- database
- extras

prefs:
  :dev_webserver: webrick
  :prod_webserver: same
  :database: sqlite
  :templates: erb
  :unit_test: rspec
  :integration: cucumber
  :fixtures: factory_girl
  :frontend: none
  :form_builder: none
  :email: gmail
  :authentication: devise
  :devise_modules: default
  :authorization: none

gems:
- heroku
- nokogiri
- kaminari

args:
  :skip_test_unit: yes
  :skip_active_record: false
```

but I'm doing something wrong, because I'm getting this error:

```
home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `add_builtin_type' for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/gems/rails_apps_composer-3.0.29/lib/rails_wizard/config.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/gems/rails_apps_composer-3.0.29/lib/rails_wizard/recipe.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/gems/rails_apps_composer-3.0.29/lib/rails_wizard.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/gems/rails_apps_composer-3.0.29/lib/rails_wizard/command.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/gems/rails_apps_composer-3.0.29/bin/rails_apps_composer:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/bin/rails_apps_composer:23:in `load'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/bin/rails_apps_composer:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/joan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@lamevapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

How can i fix it? thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to generate a new Padrino project. I'm baffled. And surprised there aren't any responses or other comments yet, even if just suggestions or speculation.